# Vincular Excel y Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint

Muy buenos días estimados. Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Estoy tratando de vincular mi planilla de Excel con una lista de Sharepoint. Lo que estoy haciendo es:

1. Desde mi lista de Sharepoint voy a Exportar>Exportar a Excel
2. Obtengo un archivo llamado "query.iqy"
3. Ejecuto dicho archivo, o también lo cargo en un libro preexistente (he probado de ambas maneras y me arroja el mismo error)
4. Me aparece una ventana de configuración llamada "Importar datos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Sin importar las opciones que elija, le doi a "Aceptar" y me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, no se me está cayendo una sola idea de por que puede estar pasando. Me fijé en las configuraciones habilitando por aquí y deshabilitando por acá pero no hay caso. Cualquier ayuda es muy bien recibida.

Cabe mencionar que no me aparece la opción de obtener datos de Sharepoint desde la misma planilla. No se si es una opción que directamente no aparece en las ultimas versiones de Excel o es particularmente mi Excel.

Desde ya muchas gracias.
Saludos.